# jQuery UI slider append "$" into the output value for display

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've been working on this slider. The slider works and displays my values to the user but I'd like the value to always be displayed with a "$" in front of it.

```
       $("#slider").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 2000,
            step: 1,
            values: [100, 1900],
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                for (var i = 0; i < ui.values.length; ++i) {
                    $("input.slidervalue[data-index=" + i + "]").val(ui.values[i]);
                }
            }
        });
        $("input.slidervalue").change(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $("#slider").slider("values", $this.data("index"), $this.val());
        });
```

How can I change this code to output the values with "$" in front of them?

[Current jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zFYjW/84/)

Comment: Simply use   `$('#total').text('$'+total);` see http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/zFYjW/83/

Comment: @DelightedD0D - sorry I pasted the wrong fiddle before. I don't think that solution applies to the real situation

Comment: Could you be more specific, you havent changed the fiddle so it's not clear what you mean by *the real situation*

Comment: just edited. Sorry about that, thanks for your patience.

Comment: No worries, same solution, you just put it in a different place, ie `.val('$'+ui.values[i]);` see http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/zFYjW/85/

Comment: that's embarrassingly simple. Thanks so much, I'm still very new to JS.

Comment: No worries, we all started there, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is concatenate the value of the slider with the "$" before you set it to the display.

Change:

```
$("input.slidervalue[data-index=" + i + "]").val(ui.values[i]);
```

To:

```
$("input.slidervalue[data-index=" + i + "]").val('$'+ui.values[i]);  // note the  '$'+
```